# ActionScript: Specification of the is operator

Tags: actionscript-3

I am having trouble googling for the expected behavior of the `is` operator in AS3. What I need to know is what should happen if the left side is `null`.

I know it is possible to test, and get empirical results, but I need to know what the specification says, and cannot find it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were not looking hard enough.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#is

"Evaluates whether an object is compatible with a specific data type, class, or interface."
Because `null` is kinda [SPECIAL CASE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/specialTypes.html#Null) and "The Null data type is special in that it is not associated with a class" you will get `false` while using it with `in` operator.

Answer (score 1):

The ActionScript 3 Language Specification says the following about [the is operator](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/specs/actionscript/3/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=as3_specification52.html#wp126215):

> The is operator checks to see if the value on the left is a member of
>   the type on the right. For user-defined types and most built-in types,
>   is returns true if the value is an instance of a class that is or
>   derives from the type on the right, otherwise it returns false.

Since `null` belongs to the [special type `Null`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/specialTypes.html) which can't be extended and cannot be used on the right side of the is operator, the is operator will always return `false`.

```
| Value | String | Number |  int  | uint  | Boolean | Object |
|-------|--------|--------|-------|-------|---------|--------|
| null  | false  | false  | false | false | false   | false  |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a bit more about how `is` operator works from this [Adobe article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f8a.html):

It shows this example:

```
if (xParam is String) { /* do some String things */ } 
else if (xParam is Number)  { /* do some Number thing */ }
```

It shows that `is` operator is for type-checking. Consider `var myNumber : dataType = new dataType`. Now is the unknown dataType classed as `Number`?, `int`?, `String`? or `Bitmap`? This method allows you to create function code that anticipates what data format is input and can deal accordingly.

You dont use `is` to check for a `null` but alternatively you can use the `==` equality operator.

```
if (xParam == null) { /* do IS NULL things */ } 
else { /* do some IS NOT NULL thing */ }
```